# Referencing JavaFX node from different controller

Tags: javafx, controller, instance, fxml

Is it possible to change the style(or any property) of a JavaFX node if the active controller is not the controller of that node?

For example, say I want to be able to change the color of an AnchorPane by clicking a button. The button and the AnchorPane have two different controllers. **How would this be achieved in the simplest way possible?**

I have looked into / tried using..

- FXML Nested Controllers http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm
- creating a function in the AnchorPane's controller class that sets the style, and calling to it when button is pressed

When following documentation on Nested Controllers, I came to a stand still after successfully getting an instance of the AnchorPane's root node - couldn't figure out how to actually change the AnchorPane.

When calling to a function in the AnchorPane's controller class that should achieve the desired effect, the AnchorPane reference would always return a null pointer error.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: If you're using `<fx:include>` to load the second fxml file, then use the nested controllers approach. Of course, you can still do the second thing you suggested: create a method in the controller that updates the style. Then you just call that method. Without seeing code it's hard to know where/why you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer out to a similar question.  It is kind of roundabout to pass data between controllers, but it is possible through the main class.  My answer to a similar question is here.

[Accessing node from outside its controller JavaFX - MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708806/accessing-node-from-outside-its-controller-javafx-mvc/35765333#35765333)

There is a tutorial linked that is also great where I learned how to do this myself.

Comment: This example really only works when you have a kind of Controller that is like an edit or settings window that is more temporary, but you could use a similar method if it was a longer term controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. One of them would be to use the controller associated with the other `Node` this is thoroughly described here (If the information flow should be the other way round, you can pass and store the parent controller to/in the child controller):

[Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Another option would be to use css selectors to access the other node `Node`, but this isn't clean design since it breaks encapsulation.

(I assumen in the following example the `id` property of the `AnchorPane` has the value `"anchorPaneId"` and that you have access to `someNodeInTheSameScene`, which is an arbitrary node in the same scene as the `AnchorPane` you're trying to access.)

```
Scene scene = someNodeInTheSameScene.getScene();
AnchorPane anchorPane = (AnchorPane) scene.lookup("#anchorPaneId");
```